# How can I accomplish this using Views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7.28 and Views 7.x-3.7.

I've created a vocabulary called Products and listed terms under this including Living, Dining, Storage, Office, Outdoor.

I've also created a content type called Products with an auto term reference for users adding content to select one of the terms.

What I want to do is create a view that will automatically create a page for each of the terms, so in the menu it will have for example Living, Dining, Storage, Office, Outdoor etc. I don't want to have to create a new view each time a term is added.

Then, if a term has been added but there is no content that has selected a term the page will just say 'No products' (which i know this bit can be done by setting a No Results behaviour.)

Thanks very much for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure whether this is exactly what you are looking for or not, but i would do it this way..

Override the taxonomy view (or clone it) from the views list. (this will override the view for all the taxonomy terms in your website.

After this install and enable the taxonomy Menu module. With this you can create a menu of the taxonomy terms for the specific content type.

For Showing the no items in the display add a "No results behavior" - under this select "Global: Unfiltered text "- click on Apply button- when the form appears put this " 'No products'" text in the text area and click on the apply button. You can also add markup for this text.
 save all the settings and check it. hope this helps

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. And there was me thinking no one would understand my question, thanks :)

Comment: Actually I had same needs and solved it in this way with some extra features

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for help with this in the future, here's how I did it:

I used the default pages that are generated for each term - I didnt realse that all terms generate a page that displays all of the content associated with them.

I then enabled and used the default Taxonomy view to edit the output of the term pages.

I also used the Taxonomy Menu module to create a menu of each taxonomy,